# hyperref warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): removing `\OT1\o'

Tags: hyperref, warnings

I'm starting to learn LaTeX using MiKTeX, but I'm stuck with a problem, that I hope you guys can help me with.

Using the document class `memoir` and a bunch of different package for graphics and page setup, I get a warning saying:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\OT1\o' on input line 3925.
```

It seems to be coming from using `\usepackage[pdfauthor={...}]{hyperref}`, but I can't find a solution for the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. However, a first shot might be adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to your document preamble.

Comment: Set the author after loading hyperref: `\hypersetup{pdfauthor={Emil Krøll}}`.

Answer (score 5):

Set the author after loading hyperref: `\hypersetup{pdfauthor={Emil Krøll}}`